# How to get Nokogiri to scrape text from span in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, curb

I'm trying to scrape information from a website using Nokogiri and Curb, but I can't seem to find the right name/ to find where to scrape. I'm trying to scrape the API key, which is at the bottom of the HTML code as "xxxxxxx".

The HTML code is:

```
    <body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-app page-app- page-app-8383900 page-app-keys i18n-en" data-twttr-rendered="true">

    <div id="skip-link"></div>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <!--

         Code for the global nav 

        -->
        <nav id="globalnav" class="without-subnav"></nav>
        <nav id="subnav"></nav>
        <section id="hero" class="hero-short"></section>

<section id="gaz-content">

    <div class="container">
        ::before
        <div id="messages"></div>
        <div id="gaz-content-wrap-outer" class="row">
            ::before
            <div id="gaz-content-wrap-inner" class="span12">
                <div class="row">
                    ::before
                    <div class="article-wrap span12">
                        <article id="gaz-content-body" class="content">
                            <header></header>
                            <div class="header-action"></div>
                            <div class="tabs"></div>

lass="d-block d-block-system g-main">

    <div class="app-details">
        <h2>

            Application Settings

        </h2>
        <div class="description"></div>
        <div class="app-settings">
            <div class="row">
                ::before
                <span class="heading">

                    Consumer Key (API Key)

                </span>
                <span>

                    xxxxxxxxx

                </span>
```

All I can seem to get is the "content" text.

My code looks like:

```
consumer = html.at("#gaz-content-body")['class']
puts consumer
```

I'm not sure what to type to select the class and/or span then the input text. All I can get is Nokogiri to put "content".

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Please read "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need the minimal input data necessary to demonstrate the problem in the question. Parsers will either reject malformed input or try to fix it, but fixing it alters it, making any resulting answers not fit the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we need to find the second `span` after the `span class="heading"`, and inside the `div class="app-settings"` - I'm  being a bit general but not too much. I'm using `search` instead of `at` to retrieve the two spans and get the second one:

```
# Gets the 2 span elements under <div class='app-settings'>.
res = html.search('#gaz-content-body .app-settings span')

# Use .text to get the contents of the 2nd element.
res[1].text.strip
# => "xxxxxxxx"
```

But you can also use `at` to target the same:

```
res = html.at("#gaz-content-body .app-settings span:nth-child(2)")
res.text.strip
# => "xxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: none of those seem to work, I either get a blank output or error reading "undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Sorry, it should work for the portion you gave of the document. Do you mind providing the whole document ?

Comment: Okay. It's giving 'content' for `html.at("#gaz-content-body")['class']` and the error for the ones I gave, right ?

Comment: You said you either get a blank output or an error, can you tell me when you get each of them ? I mean doing what causes blank and doing what causes an error.

Comment: if i use  "puts res.text" and the res = html.at("#gaz-content-body .app-settings span:nth-child(2)") i get blank
If i replace res.text with res[1].text i get an error...

Comment: Are you sure it's really blank ? There will be a lot of whitespace before 'xxxxxx' (try again with `res.strip`). And for res[1].text to work you should get the results with `res = html.search('#gaz-content-body .app-settings span')`, since it's the one that gives you an array of results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79548/discussion-between-limekin-and-marriedjane875).

Comment: the answer is "puts page.css("span")[5].text" it'll give me the xxxxx @limekin

Comment: Think it's okay for now. But it's not really a good idea to scrape it like that, because the chances of the scraping code breaking down are high when they decide to change things in the page. For instance, they might decide to add a span element in their nav or anywhere above the span you are trying to select and it can break down. So you usually should try to ignore as many portions of the page as possible by selecting specific parts (maybe meaningfully) that will contain what you are looking for. But still there are chances to not work, but lesser.

Comment: you're right, i'll look into that, thank you for everything :)